# app_offline site returning "The service is unavailable."

Tags: iis-7, app-offline.htm

I am following Scott gu's trick of placing a App_Offline.htm page at the route of my application to bring it offline - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx

It does not seem to be working on one of my sites though. I place the file in IIS7 of one my sites, and all traffic is redirected to it.

However in the other site, same server etc, I get a page that contains "The service is unavailable.".

Not sure where I am going wrong - any ideas?

Comment: i've got the same problem, did you manage to solve this yet?

Comment: unfortunately no, no solution to it.

Comment: @DevDave and amateur, I've solved the issue, check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25880018/61697

Answer (score 22):

I managed to solve it by putting the following code in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="app_offline.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <clear />
            <error statusCode="503" path="App_Offline.htm" responseMode="File" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This fix was found by putting together some info from [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/426755), [npiaseck @ IIS Forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1181179.aspx?app_offline%20doesn%20t%20display%20the%20content%20of%20the%20file%20but%20rather%20shows%20The%20service%20is%20unavailable%20) and [Kurt Schindler](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/app_offline-htm-gotchas-with-asp-net-mvc/).

Comment: The critical bit for me only seemed to be that I was missing the line inside httpErrors for the 503 response code. The other changes do not seem to be necessary.

Comment: Yep the `<httpErrors>` change for the 503 was all I needed too.

Comment: There's nothing like Googling a problem and finding a StackOverflow answer that links to a solution you posted six years earlier because you apparently had this problem before and forgot you had it and how you solved it ;)

Answer (score 12):

this was my soluton - notice the 503...

```
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='-1' />
  <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode='-1' />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode='-1' />
  <remove statusCode="503" subStatusCode='-1' />
  <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="File" />
  <error statusCode="400" path="404.html" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="File" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="File" />
  <error statusCode="503" path="app_offline.htm" responseMode="File" />

</httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with a MVC site recently, and I managed to solve it by replacing the web.config I originally had with a clean, minimal one when wanting to use the app_offline.htm file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I had more time I'd go through and find the exact thing in the web.config that was altering the behaviour, but this is worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently when adding a `app_offline.htm` page to one of my sites.

All the answers here suggest to set the 503 response to the same `app_offline.htm`, I already have a different 503 page and don't really want to fiddle with that.

Also, I liked to know why this is happening.

The `503` is sent by the AspNetInitializationExceptionModule, I assume if the asp.net runtime detects the `app_offline.htm` file in the root of the web site, it sends an

```
503 Service Unavailable
```

and also does send the content of the `app_offline.htm` as a response.

However, because it is an error response the IIS error handing kicks in:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace">
```

The `Replace` here means, ignore whatever ASP.NET sent you and use your own 503 response. By specifying the same page (`app_offline.htm`) like suggested in the other answers this fixes the problem.

Another way to fix this is to change the existingResponse attribute, like:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Auto">
```

now IIS honours the response from ASP.NET and shows the content of the `app_offline.htm` file.

But `Auto` also means that other ASP.NET error responses may pass through.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it using the GUI (note the last line - that's the one you should add/edit)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is rename your web.config to something else like web.config.bak while using the app_offline.htm.